# Wowza Bitmap Overlay not working on click

Tags: overlay, wowza

I am using Wowza GoCoder SDK for Android to stream video and now I am adding a graphic overly as shown in the docs example:

```
// Read in a PNG file from the app resources as a bitmap
    Bitmap overlayBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.overlay_logo);

    // Initialize a bitmap renderer with the bitmap
    mWZBitmap = new WZBitmap(overlayBitmap);

    // Place the bitmap at top left of the display
    mWZBitmap.setPosition(WZBitmap.LEFT, WZBitmap.TOP);

    // Scale the bitmap initially to 75% of the display surface width
    mWZBitmap.setScale(0.75f, WZBitmap.SURFACE_WIDTH);

    // Register the bitmap renderer with the GoCoder camera preview view as a frame listener
    mWZCameraView.registerFrameRenderer(mWZBitmap);
```

It works perfectly as long as I put it directly in the onCreate() method, however if I try to use a button to add the bitmap overlay using onClickListener it fails with an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: VideoViewRenderer
Process: com.streamland.livenia_android, PID: 27284
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
    at android.opengl.Matrix.setIdentityM(Matrix.java:426)
    at com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.api.android.graphics.WOWZBitmap.recomputeView(WOWZBitmap.java:399)
    at com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.api.android.graphics.WOWZBitmap.onWZVideoFrameRendererDraw(WOWZBitmap.java:349)
    at com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.support.render.VideoViewRenderer.onDrawFrame(VideoViewRenderer.java:556)
    at com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.support.render.VideoViewRenderer.access$600(VideoViewRenderer.java:58)
    at com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.support.render.VideoViewRenderer$RendererHandler.handleMessage(VideoViewRenderer.java:827)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.support.render.VideoViewRenderer$1.run(VideoViewRenderer.java:276)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: What version of GoCoder Android SDK are you using? The GoCoder SDK sample app includes an example, but it has similar code in the onResume() method. I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: I am using Wowza GoCoder SDK 1.8.0 build 0463, I actually got the code from the sample and the only change I made was add the bitmap on a button listener instead of onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Wowza did correct some issues with the bitmap overlay in the most recent version of the Android SDK which is 1.8.0 build 0463.  Can you confirm which SDK version you are using?

Comment: I am using latest version Wowza GoCoder SDK 1.8.0 build 0463, luckily I was able to sort of solve my problem but not the sdk issue itself